# Kusto database creation datetime

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

We need to cleanup Kusto databases in a cluster that we have created and ***are not getting used*** thus have **0 size**.  I'm planning to use powershell script for it and can perform it using combination of [Get-AzKustoDatabase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.kusto/get-azkustodatabase?view=azps-7.2.0) command and filtering out the databases with size 0 and using
[Remove-AzKustoDatabase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.kusto/remove-azkustodatabase?view=azps-7.2.0)  command

However, I need to know if the database was not created recently (say 10 days back) before removing it. Is there any way we can identify kusto database creation date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the database was created during the last 365 days, you can find an entry for its creation on the Journal: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/journal

Comment: Thank you, Yoni! I was able to check Journal using query below and identify when the create database command was executed.                                                                                      `.show database ['databasename'] journal
| where Event == 'ADD-DATABASE'`